# How to write inside HTTP body in windows phone 7.5

Tags: http, windows-phone-7

I need to confirm before trying, How can I write  a string inside HTTP body to send to a php page from Windows phone 7.5.

Does `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream()` write to HTTP body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple question, direct answer: yes!

You should use the [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to send the HTTP request body, (example: use it to send a POST request data)

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation. That saved my time.